# Why do I get an Xml Validation error when running my application on one server, but not on my other server's systems?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-validation, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I've deployed my ASP.Net C# application to three other systems without problem. I haven't changed the application code, or even the installer. I have also gone through and made sure that my IIS 10 settings and connections are all set up as close to the other environments as possible. One of the systems/environments that the application runs successfully on is running Windows Server 2008 alongside IIS 7, while the other two are running Windows 10 and IIS 10. The system the application fails on is running Windows Server 2019 and IIS 10. What I don't understand is why I would be getting this error, when I haven't changed anything other than the system and server my application is running on:

```
XmlValidator::ValidateXml() - Error Validating xml - System.Exception:  Validation error: The element 'systemBalances' in namespace 'http://www.alpha.com/system/schemas/v1.0/' has invalid child element 'accessible' in namespace 'http://www.alpha.com/system/schemas/v1.0/'.

   at ABC.Common.XMLValidators.XmlValidator.ValidationHandler(Object sender, ValidationEventArgs args) in C:\XYZ Src\Dev\ABC\ABC[Dev]\AlphaWebServices\ABC.Common\XmlValidator.cs:line 134
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(ValidationEventHandler eventHandler, Object sender, XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ElementValidationError(XmlQualifiedName name, ValidationState context, ValidationEventHandler eventHandler, Object sender, String sourceUri, Int32 lineNo, Int32 linePos, XmlSchemaSet schemaSet)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateElementContext(XmlQualifiedName elementName, Boolean& invalidElementInContext)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateElement(String localName, String namespaceUri, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo, String xsiType, String xsiNil, String xsiSchemaLocation, String xsiNoNamespaceSchemaLocation)
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessReaderEvent()
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
   at ABC.Common.XMLValidators.XmlValidator.ValidateXml(String sXmlToValidate, JKLClass AlphaClass, Int32 hostId, String egmId, String& outXmlMsg) in C:\BMS Src\Dev\ABC\ABC[Dev]\AlphaWebServices\ABC.Common\XmlValidator.cs:line 34
```

I'm not sure if it matters but the three other systems that my application is running on successfully are all hosted on the same server while the one that errors is on a server separate from the initial three environments.

Comment: Could you share the schema? Is the encoding defined in the xml documents that are validated? Maybe there's some mismatch in the default code pages between the different servers?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference because I used the same installer on all the environments and the service the installer is installing contains the XML Schemas in the code/project itself, so they also wouldn't change between servers. FYI The message going out also doesn't change as I can just change the address that message is going to, to one of the working environments, and they accept it no problem. I can add the relevant part of the schema to my original question, but I'm not sure it will help!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you're validating the same XML file on both servers?

Comment: @ScottHannen Oh absolutely, the XML Schemas are built into the project itself and the messages going out from the other service are from the exact same service; just one service running on one server in one place, one little dude hanging out :)

Comment: Memory/disk issue?

Comment: @LexLi entirely possible, there's not a lot of space allocated for this environment, how would I go about checking that?

Comment: @LexLi  I checked the task manager and although there's a spike in my CPU usage  (as expected) when sending the message to my broken service, nothing seems to max out.